# how to prove that (P⊃Q)≡(¬Q⊃¬P) ( P ⊃ Q ) ≡ ( ¬ Q ⊃ ¬ P ) is disallowed in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

this is what I've tried;

define kripke model K=({0,1},≤,⊩) where ≤ is the (total) order relation over {0,1} defined by
0≤0 0≤ 11≤1,and ⊩ is a binary relation from {0,1} to the set of propositional variables such that 0⊮A and 1⊩A and 1⊮B and 0⊩B. then

1⊮(A⊃B)≡(¬B⊃¬A) ( B ⊃ A ) ≡ ( ¬ B ⊃ ¬ A )

can somebody tell me if this is correct or if there are errors, what are they and how can they be corrected?

Comment: A special case of that with $P = \top$ would be $Q \equiv \lnot \lnot Q$...

Comment: @DanielSchepler P=T? could you please clarify what you mean? I appreciate you trying to help and I need to know how to prove this soon

Comment: I'm not sure what your question here is.  If $P$ is the true proposition, then $(P \supset Q) = (\top \supset Q) \equiv Q$ and $(\lnot Q \supset \lnot P) = (\lnot Q \supset \lnot \top) \equiv (\lnot Q \supset \bot) \equiv \lnot \lnot Q$.

Comment: In a Kripke model, if $0 \Vdash B$ and $0 \leq 1$, then $1 \Vdash B$ too—theorem’s can’t become “unproved”.

Comment: Is the argument supposed to start by supposing either $(\lnot B \subset \lnot A)$, $(A \subset B) \equiv (\lnot B \subset \lnot A)$, or [insert some other initial hypothesis here]?

Comment: (If $x \notin A$, then $x \notin B$) $\equiv$ (If not $x \notin B$, then not $x \notin A$) $\equiv$ (If $x \in B$, then $x \in A$). The first equivalence follows from the Law of Contraposition. The second equivalence follows from the principle of double negation which has the symbolic form $(\lnot \lnot P \iff  P)$. The forward implication $(\lnot \lnot P \implies P)$ is equivalent to the Law of Excluded Middle. The means by which the purported argument follows seem vague but LEM is obviously a nonconstructive principle.

Comment: Already asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001601/how-to-prove-that-in-intuitionistic-logic-the-contrapositive-law-is-disallowed).

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused by your notation, so I think this may only be a partial answer, but I hope it helps.

Note that intuitionistically, as classically, $(A \supset B) \supset (\lnot B \supset \lnot A)$; so to show that the two aren't equivalent, we're going to have to produce a counterexample to $(\lnot B \supset \lnot A) \supset (A \supset B)$.

I'm assuming you are familiar with Kripke semantics (quick reminder here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3027858/446689). Consider this structure:

[image]

- Since $1\Vdash B$, we have $0\not\Vdash\lnot B$ and $1\not\Vdash\lnot B$, so $0\Vdash (\lnot B \supset \lnot A)$.
- On the other hand, $0\Vdash A$ but $0\not\Vdash B$, so $0\not\Vdash (A \supset B)$.

Therefore, $0\not\Vdash (\lnot B \supset \lnot A) \supset (A \supset B)$, and so $0\not\Vdash (A \supset B) \equiv (\lnot B \supset \lnot A)$.

---

You also seem to consider $(B \supset A) \equiv (\lnot B \supset \lnot A)$, but this is even classically false!